# How to check the variable unused in OC or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, properties

so, everyone If I write a property, but I don't use.
for example：

`@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray  *array;`

but,I don't use array. so How can I check the variable like'array'?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to ensure your code quality. You can detect such issue by using the following methods.

1. Xcode's `Analyze` function

[image]

2. Linting the language you use

   - [oclint](http://oclint.org)
   - [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)
3. Using Sonarqube to detect code smells and enforcing quality gate

   - [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mentioned tools, [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) does it very well. It will analyze the code if you open a file, or as you type it, and it will visually show that the variable is unused.